# SQLite JOIN on zero if ID not in data set

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, "base" and "override", in a SQLite database I need to join together on base.ID and override.BaseID with the MIN(override.Priority).  Override.BaseID can be '0', in which case means the override is "global" and applies to all base records unless an override record with the BaseID exists and has an equal or lower override.Priority value.  It's also possible to have no global override record at all, meaning I only want to return the base record if they have a corresponding override.BaseID record present.  I can do this in memory or in a stored procedure, but is there a way to do it all in one query?

For example, here's some "base" data:

```
ID | Name
----------
1  | Test1
2  | Test2
3  | Test3
```

And here's some "override" data:

```
ID | BaseID | Priority | Authorized
-----------------------------------
1  | 1      | 1        | 0
2  | 3      | 1        | 1
3  | 0      | 2        | 1
```

And here's what I want the query to return:

```
base.ID | base.Name | override.ID | override.Authorized
-------------------------------------------------------
1       | Test1     | 1           | 0
2       | Test2     | 3           | 1
3       | Test3     | 2           | 1
```

If we were to remove override.ID '3' I would expect the following:

```
base.ID | base.Name | override.ID | override.Authorized
-------------------------------------------------------
1       | Test1     | 1           | 0
3       | Test3     | 2           | 1
```

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: @CL added sample data!

Comment: Can there be multiple overrides for the same `BaseID`?

Comment: @CL yes, that is possible, so I need the one with the smallest Priority value

Comment: @CL I should also add if the Priority of the global row is a lower value than the Priority of the non-global row then the global row should take precedence.  Also, it's possible to have multiple global rows of varying priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this:

First, look for the lowest Priority global override (if it exists) and inner join it to the base set (which prevents any base rows from returning if there's no global override), and add a '.1' to the Priority:

```
SELECT *
FROM base
JOIN (SELECT ID AS OverrideID, BaseID, Authorized, MIN(Priority) + '.1' AS Priority
    FROM override
    WHERE BaseID = 0)
```

Then find the lowest priority non-global overrides grouped by BaseID, inner join the base table on base.ID, and add a '.0' to the Priority:

```
SELECT *
FROM base b
JOIN (SELECT ID AS OverrideID, BaseID, Authorized, MIN(Priority) + '.0' AS Priority
    FROM override
    WHERE BaseID != 0
    GROUP BY BaseID) o ON b.ID = o.BaseID
```

Finally, UNION the two data sets and select the lowest Priority value grouped by base.ID:

```
SELECT *, MIN(Priority)
FROM (SELECT *
    FROM base
    JOIN (SELECT ID AS OverrideID, BaseID, Authorized, MIN(Priority) + '.1' AS Priority
        FROM override
        WHERE BaseID = 0)
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM base b
    JOIN (SELECT ID AS OverrideID, BaseID, Authorized, MIN(Priority) + '.0' AS Priority
        FROM override
        WHERE BaseID != 0
        GROUP BY BaseID) o ON b.ID = o.BaseID)
GROUP BY ID;
```

The concatenated decimal points act as a tiebreaker in case the Priority of a global and non-global override are the same, granting preference to the non-global.  This seems to work thus far.  It likely can be refactored for more efficiency, but it is accurate and fast enough for my purposes.

UPDATE:

Wow.  Well, I got a bit bored and decided to refactor.  I was able to drastically simplify the query:

```
SELECT *, MIN(override.Priority + CASE WHEN override.BaseID = 0 THEN '.1' ELSE '.0' END)
FROM base
JOIN override ON (override.BaseID = 0 OR override.BaseID = base.ID)
GROUP BY base.ID;
```

I wish I didn't have to do the concat in the MIN() function, and if I didn't have to worry about tiebreakers I wouldn't need it, but this seems like a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

First get the rows with the smallest priority value for each base ID. (Using MIN() this way requires SQLite 3.7.11 or later.)

```
SELECT ID,
       BaseID,
       MIN(Prority) AS Priority,
       Authorized
FROM override;
```

Then filter out any of those rows that are invalid due to a gloval override:

```
...
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM override AS g
                  WHERE g.BaseID   = 0
                    AND g.Priority < override.Priority);
```

This can then just be joined:

```
SELECT base.ID,
       base.Name,
       o.ID,
       o.Authorized
FROM base
JOIN (SELECT ID,
             BaseID,
             MIN(Prority) AS Priority,
             Authorized
      FROM override
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM override AS g
                        WHERE g.BaseID   = 0
                          AND g.Priority < override.Priority)
     ) AS o
     ON base.ID = o.BaseID OR o.BaseID = 0;
```

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't this miss joining base to overrides with zero IDs since you're joining on base.ID = o.BaseID?